# How to print values from a DataGridView control

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview

I have an application that has a `DataGridView` control, which holds data that I want to print out when the "print" button is pushed.

So far I have got the "print" button working, but when I print on the application the page comes out blank!

How do I edit my code to enable the data to be printed?

```
public partial class frmViewBookings : Form
{
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 mainpage = new Form3();
        mainpage.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void frmViewBookings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.bookingTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet1.Booking);
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        var myPaintArgs = new PaintEventArgs
        (
            e.Graphics,
            new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), this.Size)
        );

        this.InvokePaint(dataGridView1, myPaintArgs);
    } 

    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I previously Test this class for Print `data grid view` content

Add this class to your project:

```
  class ClsPrint
    {
        #region Variables

        int iCellHeight = 0; //Used to get/set the datagridview cell height
        int iTotalWidth = 0; //
        int iRow = 0;//Used as counter
        bool bFirstPage = false; //Used to check whether we are printing first page
        bool bNewPage = false;// Used to check whether we are printing a new page
        int iHeaderHeight = 0; //Used for the header height
        StringFormat strFormat; //Used to format the grid rows.
        ArrayList arrColumnLefts = new ArrayList();//Used to save left coordinates of columns
        ArrayList arrColumnWidths = new ArrayList();//Used to save column widths
        private PrintDocument _printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        private DataGridView gw = new DataGridView();
        private string _ReportHeader;

        #endregion

        public ClsPrint(DataGridView gridview, string ReportHeader)
        {
            _printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(_printDocument_PrintPage);
            _printDocument.BeginPrint += new PrintEventHandler(_printDocument_BeginPrint);
            gw = gridview;
            _ReportHeader = ReportHeader;
        }

        public void PrintForm()
        {
            ////Open the print dialog
            //PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            //printDialog.Document = _printDocument;
            //printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;

            ////Get the document
            //if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
            //{
            //    _printDocument.DocumentName = "Test Page Print";
            //    _printDocument.Print();
            //}

            //Open the print preview dialog
            PrintPreviewDialog objPPdialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            objPPdialog.Document = _printDocument;
            objPPdialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void _printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //try
            //{
            //Set the left margin
            int iLeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            //Set the top margin
            int iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            //Whether more pages have to print or not
            bool bMorePagesToPrint = false;
            int iTmpWidth = 0;

            //For the first page to print set the cell width and header height
            if (bFirstPage)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in gw.Columns)
                {
                    iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width /
                        (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth *
                        ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))));

                    iHeaderHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText,
                        GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height) + 11;

                    // Save width and height of headers
                    arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin);
                    arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth);
                    iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth;
                }
            }
            //Loop till all the grid rows not get printed
            while (iRow <= gw.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                DataGridViewRow GridRow = gw.Rows[iRow];
                //Set the cell height
                iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5;
                int iCount = 0;
                //Check whether the current page settings allows more rows to print
                if (iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
                {
                    bNewPage = true;
                    bFirstPage = false;
                    bMorePagesToPrint = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                    if (bNewPage)
                    {
                        //Draw Header
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(_ReportHeader,
                            new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left,
                            e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString(_ReportHeader,
                            new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                        String strDate = "";
                        //Draw Date
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate,
                            new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black,
                            e.MarginBounds.Left +
                            (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate,
                            new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            e.MarginBounds.Width).Width),
                            e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString(_ReportHeader,
                            new Font(new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                        //Draw Columns                 
                        iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                        DataGridViewColumn[] _GridCol = new DataGridViewColumn[gw.Columns.Count];
                        int colcount = 0;
                        //Convert ltr to rtl
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in gw.Columns)
                        {
                            _GridCol[colcount++] = GridCol;
                        }
                        for (int i = (_GridCol.Count() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray),
                                new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                                new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawString(_GridCol[i].HeaderText,
                                _GridCol[i].InheritedStyle.Font,
                                new SolidBrush(_GridCol[i].InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);
                            iCount++;
                        }
                        bNewPage = false;
                        iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight;
                    }
                    iCount = 0;
                    DataGridViewCell[] _GridCell = new DataGridViewCell[GridRow.Cells.Count];
                    int cellcount = 0;
                    //Convert ltr to rtl
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                    {
                        _GridCell[cellcount++] = Cel;
                    }
                    //Draw Columns Contents                
                    for (int i = (_GridCell.Count() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (_GridCell[i].Value != null)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(_GridCell[i].FormattedValue.ToString(),
                                _GridCell[i].InheritedStyle.Font,
                                new SolidBrush(_GridCell[i].InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],
                                (float)iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight),
                                strFormat);
                        }
                        //Drawing Cells Borders 
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                            new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));
                        iCount++;
                    }
                }
                iRow++;
                iTopMargin += iCellHeight;
            }
            //If more lines exist, print another page.
            if (bMorePagesToPrint)
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            else
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            //}
            //catch (Exception exc)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            //       MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            //}
        }

        private void _printDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                strFormat = new StringFormat();
                strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;

                arrColumnLefts.Clear();
                arrColumnWidths.Clear();
                iCellHeight = 0;
                iRow = 0;
                bFirstPage = true;
                bNewPage = true;

                // Calculating Total Widths
                iTotalWidth = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in gw.Columns)
                {
                    iTotalWidth += dgvGridCol.Width;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

    }
```

**For using:** this will show print dialog with grid view result

```
ClsPrint _ClsPrint = new ClsPrint(dataGridView1, "header doc text");
 _ClsPrint.PrintForm();
```

### Result

[image]

[Further information and full example proejct](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView)

**EDIT**

To get columns in right order (rather than having them in reversed order), do this:

```
  int colcount = gw.Columns.Count - 1;
                        //Convert ltr to rtl
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in gw.Columns)
                        {
                            _GridCol[colcount--] = GridCol;
                        }
```

and

```
 int cellcount = GridRow.Cells.Count - 1;
                    //Convert ltr to rtl
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                    {
                        _GridCell[cellcount--] = Cel;
                    }
```

Comment: isnt there a simpler way to do this? as in not a seperate class

Comment: @bandaa:I thik this is the best way,but there is another example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWinFormPrintDataGridView-75864c45

Comment: The columns come out in random order

Comment: I believe that the orig source for this was http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView complete with download example project

Comment: @IRSOG - maybe you should have credited the orig author?

Comment: The columns are not in the right order can you fix this?

Comment: @ryan , the code was taken from code project but I don't have it off the top of my head .

Comment: Yes @KF2 - I found out the orig one for you with a simple google search. See comments above nearly a year ago. Going to edit your question to credit orig author - something you should have done yourself.

Answer (score 3):

When using IRSOG's code, change the direction of the loops below Convert ltr to rtl for regular results. Otherwise the whole dgv would be flipped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Visual Studio 2010.
2. Create new project and give appropriate name.
3. Drag and drop datagridview in your form from toolbox.
4. Add data in the datagridview.
5. Drag and drop the printDocument from toolbox.
6. Add a button for print on the form.
7. Double click to get the click event of button.
8. Write the below code in print button click event.
   printDocument1.Print();
9. Double click on the printDocument to get the Print Page event.
10. Write the below code for print the datagridview:-

    ```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);

        dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
    }
    ```

source 
https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1356/datagridview-printing-in-c-sharp

this will work exactly

Comment: thats would be great if we are able to customize header row and footer row instead of the `datagridview` headers