# PrintDialog.PrinterSettings not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to print the selected file from datagridview. This file location is saved in the database. Now before printing I want to pass "number of copies, from page & to page" to the PrintDialog. I am able to pass these values to the PrintDialog, but it is not working and all the pages are being print and that too only once. I even searched a lot to find it on net but was unable to solve this.

Please help me to print 'n' no of copies either by selecting all page option or by passing values to FromPage and ToPage. my code is :

```
//string ASSIGNMENT_PATH = dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
string ASSIGNMENT_PATH = "@C:\test.docx";

if (!File.Exists(ASSIGNMENT_PATH))
{
    MessageBox.Show("No exceptional file created by application till now .");
}
else
{
    short noC = Convert.ToInt16(txtNumOfCopies.Text);
    short fP = Convert.ToInt16(txtFromPage.Text);
    short tP = Convert.ToInt16(txtToPage.Text);

    PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
    dialog.AllowSomePages = true;
    dialog.PrinterSettings.FromPage = fP;
    dialog.PrinterSettings.ToPage = tP;
    dialog.PrinterSettings.Copies = noC;

    DialogResult dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog(this);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(ASSIGNMENT_PATH);
        info.Verb = "PrintTo";
        info.Arguments = "\"" + printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\"";
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(info);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stanislav Ageyev is right that you should use either `PrintDocument` object or shell command `printto`. No any surprise that you got printed all pages because your use shell command. you can't pass any parameters from your `PrintDialog` object to shell. As I understand you want print file selected from datagrid, so please consider approach to write your own code of printing via `PrintDocument`. If you want print some specific file like 'Word,Excel' consider using Office.Interop.

Comment: @Alezis I may be wrong in writing this code, but can u help me by providing correct code or please edit my code and make it correct.

Comment: I don't know what file type you want to print. In your case, when user can adjust page range, I suggest to look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx. Scroll down and you will see example of code. This is approach 1. Printing via `print` or `printto` (approach 2) commands is not fit to you, I think, because I don't remember any parameter how to path range of pages or copy's count.

Comment: Which type of document you like print?

Comment: this code which i have written prints all file formats(.docx, .pptx, .xls, ,txt. .png, .jpg, etc) as it just print the file at the path we provide to it. you can use this code and check it yourself. but the link you have send is not help full to me. Well I want to print .docx file type.

Comment: So as I understand you want to support ANY file type. and you want print ANY of this file via shell command "printto". However if OS does no contain corresponding application for that file type you get exception "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation". Thus you should make sure that the Word or PowerPoint installed on the target PC. Approach with `Document` is not good idea because you should support many file types and implementation all of these is really challenge. I suggest to find some another workaround and share with us.

Answer (score 0):

At this code you use 2 methods of prints.

1. First method, with PrintDialog, *Its not working at your case* because you must set Document property.
2. Second method, with Process class and all Pages prints because you send to printer whole files at argument.

It`s example for print DataGridView  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView or you can also try this [How to print values from a DataGridView control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853746/how-to-print-datagridview-data-on-winforms)

Comment: I am using PrintDialog to show dialog box and to set printersettings. and process to print the selected file. well i don't want to print DataGridView I want to print the file whose path is shown in DataGridView. or say ASSIGNMENT_PATH contains a path to the file. I want to print that file with my conditions.