# How to Print DatagridView?

Tags: vb.net

I am using simple data grid view for displaying all records using select statement in stored Procedure...the displayed list view is okay i want to print it out as it is. What should i do 
like we print the excel sheets...

Thanks For The Solution In Advance..

My Logic For Filling Data Grid View Is :

```
Public Sub FillDataGrid(ByVal myGrid As DataGridView, ByVal Sqlstring As String)
    myGrid.Enabled = False
    Dim myDbf As New SqlDataAdapter(Sqlstring, myConnection)
    Dim myDataset As New DataSet
    myDataset.Clear()
    myDbf.Fill(myDataset, "Finddata")
    myDataset.Tables("Finddata").DefaultView.AllowNew = False
    myGrid.DataSource = myDataset.Tables("FindData")
    myGrid.AutoResizeColumns()
    myGrid.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Above function will be called on level from module by passing datagrid & stored procedure in parameters.

Comment: What do you actually want? your grid will be filled from this function what do you need? you want to export this grid data in excel sheet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to print datagridview data on winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853746/how-to-print-datagridview-data-on-winforms)

Comment: The DataGridView doesn't have inbuilt printing functionality. See the above SO question for printing datagrdiview. Also see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView) article from codeproject.