# Wrong column order when printing from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview

I'm trying to print data from a `DataGridView` using this class that I found in another post:
[How to print values from a DataGridView control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853746/how-to-print-values-from-a-datagridview-control), but I get the columns in the wrong order.

```
class ClsPrint
{
    #region Variables

    int iCellHeight = 0; //Used to get/set the datagridview cell height
    int iTotalWidth = 0; //
    int iRow = 0;//Used as counter
    bool bFirstPage = false; //Used to check whether we are printing first page
    bool bNewPage = false;// Used to check whether we are printing a new page
    int iHeaderHeight = 0; //Used for the header height
    StringFormat strFormat; //Used to format the grid rows.
    ArrayList arrColumnLefts = new ArrayList();//Used to save left coordinates of columns
    ArrayList arrColumnWidths = new ArrayList();//Used to save column widths
    private PrintDocument _printDocument = new PrintDocument();
    private DataGridView gw = new DataGridView();
    private string _ReportHeader;

    #endregion

    public ClsPrint(DataGridView gridview, string ReportHeader)
    {
        _printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(_printDocument_PrintPage);
        _printDocument.BeginPrint += new PrintEventHandler(_printDocument_BeginPrint);
        gw = gridview;
        _ReportHeader = ReportHeader;
    }

    public void PrintForm()
    {
        ////Open the print dialog
        //PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        //printDialog.Document = _printDocument;
        //printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;

        ////Get the document
        //if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
        //{
        //    _printDocument.DocumentName = "Test Page Print";
        //    _printDocument.Print();
        //}

        //Open the print preview dialog
        PrintPreviewDialog objPPdialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        objPPdialog.Document = _printDocument;
        objPPdialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void _printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
        //Set the left margin
        int iLeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        //Set the top margin
        int iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        //Whether more pages have to print or not
        bool bMorePagesToPrint = false;
        int iTmpWidth = 0;

        //For the first page to print set the cell width and header height
        if (bFirstPage)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in gw.Columns)
            {
                iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width /
                    (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth *
                    ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))));

                iHeaderHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText,
                    GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height) + 11;

                // Save width and height of headers
                arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin);
                arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth);
                iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth;
            }
        }
        //Loop till all the grid rows not get printed
        while (iRow <= gw.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            DataGridViewRow GridRow = gw.Rows[iRow];
            //Set the cell height
            iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5;
            int iCount = 0;
            //Check whether the current page settings allows more rows to print
            if (iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
            {
                bNewPage = true;
                bFirstPage = false;
                bMorePagesToPrint = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (bNewPage)
                {
                    //Draw Header
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(_ReportHeader,
                        new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                        Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left,
                        e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString(_ReportHeader,
                        new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                        e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                    String strDate = "";
                    //Draw Date
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate,
                        new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black,
                        e.MarginBounds.Left +
                        (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate,
                        new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                        e.MarginBounds.Width).Width),
                        e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString(_ReportHeader,
                        new Font(new Font(gw.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                        FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                    //Draw Columns                 
                    iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                    DataGridViewColumn[] _GridCol = new DataGridViewColumn[gw.Columns.Count];
                    int colcount = 0;
                    //Convert ltr to rtl
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in gw.Columns)
                    {
                        _GridCol[colcount++] = GridCol;
                    }
                    for (int i = (_GridCol.Count() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray),
                            new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                            new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                        e.Graphics.DrawString(_GridCol[i].HeaderText,
                            _GridCol[i].InheritedStyle.Font,
                            new SolidBrush(_GridCol[i].InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                            new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);
                        iCount++;
                    }
                    bNewPage = false;
                    iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight;
                }
                iCount = 0;
                DataGridViewCell[] _GridCell = new DataGridViewCell[GridRow.Cells.Count];
                int cellcount = 0;
                //Convert ltr to rtl
                foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                {
                    _GridCell[cellcount++] = Cel;
                }
                //Draw Columns Contents                
                for (int i = (_GridCell.Count() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (_GridCell[i].Value != null)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(_GridCell[i].FormattedValue.ToString(),
                            _GridCell[i].InheritedStyle.Font,
                            new SolidBrush(_GridCell[i].InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                            new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],
                            (float)iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight),
                            strFormat);
                    }
                    //Drawing Cells Borders 
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                        new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                        (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));
                    iCount++;
                }
            }
            iRow++;
            iTopMargin += iCellHeight;
        }
        //If more lines exist, print another page.
        if (bMorePagesToPrint)
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        //}
        //catch (Exception exc)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        //       MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        //}
    }

    private void _printDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            strFormat = new StringFormat();
            strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;

            arrColumnLefts.Clear();
            arrColumnWidths.Clear();
            iCellHeight = 0;
            iRow = 0;
            bFirstPage = true;
            bNewPage = true;

            // Calculating Total Widths
            iTotalWidth = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in gw.Columns)
            {
                iTotalWidth += dgvGridCol.Width;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

For example, here is a DataGridView from my project:

[image: Original order]

And this is the print page I get (wrong column order):

[image: Wrong order]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two indexes, one goes forward and the other backwards:

```
            for (int i = (_GridCell.Count() - 1); i >= 0; i--) // i goes from count - 1 to 0
            {
                if (_GridCell[i].Value != null)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(_GridCell[i].FormattedValue.ToString(),
                        _GridCell[i].InheritedStyle.Font,
                        new SolidBrush(_GridCell[i].InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                        new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],
                        (float)iTopMargin,
                        (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight),
                        strFormat);
                }
                //Drawing Cells Borders 
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                    new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                    (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));

                iCount++; //iCount goes from 0 to count - 1
            }
```

Use the same index for retrieving the position and the grid content:

```
            for (int i = (_GridCell.Count() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (_GridCell[i].Value != null)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(_GridCell[i].FormattedValue.ToString(),
                        _GridCell[i].InheritedStyle.Font,
                        new SolidBrush(_GridCell[i].InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                        new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[i],
                        (float)iTopMargin,
                        (int)arrColumnWidths[i], (float)iCellHeight),
                        strFormat);
                }
                //Drawing Cells Borders 
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                    new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[i], iTopMargin,
                    (int)arrColumnWidths[i], iCellHeight));
            }
```

Remember to do the same on the headers.

Comment: I have made the changes and now it works correctly. 
I'm immensely grateful